# Novel with silver metal-like parasites that controlled and destroyed their hosts' brain

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been trying to remember the title of a book that I read perhaps thirty years ago. The setting was in star ships in deep space. The main topic was a metallic, tear shaped parasite that infected human brains and controlled their thoughts and actions. Eventually, the parasite would destroy the human host it controlled.

Apparently, that's all I really remember about the book, other than the fact that the parasite was part of a larger helmet which was revealed in the last chapters.

Comment: Can you clarify what "the parasite was part of a larger helmet" means? The parasites were part of some larger mechanism? Or the parasites are controlled by someone wearing a helmet?